# How should i structure my bitbucket repositories

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-branch, directory-structure

I looked around but i couldn't find any answers that i needed. I was recommended by my professor to upload my school work to bitbucket. I figured how to upload my work but i am confused on how i should structure my repositories and projects. i have multiple classes and multiple assignments for each class. should each class have its own repository with branches in each repository for assignments or should each assignment have it own repository? there is also the option of creating projects on bitbucket but that requires teams and i dont know if i should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would prefer each class to have its own repo is they are unrelated.
BUT, there is the possibility of putting everything in one repo and committing each class to a distinct branch. as long as you don't merge them, you could easily checkout between them.
Also, tools like GitLab allow you to define tickets and open branches for those tickets so if each class has multiple assignments, gitlab will allow you to easily open and monitor a branch for each assignment on each repo.

Those are my 2 cents. If you have any questions, don't hesitate :)